# EJB Look up failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb/CategoryFacade'

Tags: java, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I am not much aware of EJB, please execuse me if I am asking something obvious. This is my EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class CategoryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Category> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategoryFacade() {
        super(Category.class);
    }
}
```

I have a class called `AffableBeanService`, basically it is a REST service class. In this I am trying to invoke EJB as below:

```
@GET
@Path("/categories/{categoryId}")
public String getInfo(@PathParam("categoryId") String categoryId) {
    //Note I have removed try, catch etc to save the space
    CategoryFacade categoryFacade; //This is a class, not a interface

    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    categoryFacade = (CategoryFacade)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/CategoryFacade");
}
```

At run time I am getting exception as `javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:/env/ejb/CategoryFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv`. I am not sure, what I am missing here. Can anyone please help me?

Also I tried like this:

```
@EJB
CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
```

But again EJB injection not happening and I am getting NullPointerException. I assume I am missing some configuration or I am not sure if I am invoking EJB in right way. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,  I am able to resolve it myself. What I was trying to access is EJB from a Rest Service. In order to make it work, I made the rest service class itself as a EJB like below:

```
@Stateless    //This made trick
@Path("/service")
public class AffableBeanService {
    //EJB Injection
    @EJB
    CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

    @GET
    @Path("/categories/{categoryId}")
    public String categories(@PathParam("categoryId") String categoryId) {
         selectedCategory = categoryFacade.find(Short.parseShort(categoryId));
    }
}
```

So now I am able to call EJB without JNDI look up and injection is working fine.